# Creating <button> with jQuery ignores type attribute

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to create a couple of buttons using jQuery, with commands like this:

```
$('<button></button>', { type: 'reset', id: 'reset', name: 'reset' })
    .text('Reset all fields').appendTo(target);
```

This works pretty well, except that the buttons are created without the `type` attribute.

This is what I want:

```
<button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">Reset all fields</button>
```

but I get this:

```
<button id="reset" name="reset">Reset all fields</button>
```

i.e. the `type="reset"` is missing. I've tried adding it separately with `.attr()`, but it doesn't help. The attribute is simply ignored. What am I missing here?

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4. As noted in comments, this works in the latest jQuery version, but that's not the one in our system and I don't know what things might break if we upgrade, so I'd prefer to solve this with the existing version.

Comment: In what browser? I tried this fiddle in Firefox 5 and Chrome 12 and it seems to have the `type` attribute if you right click -> Inspect Element. http://jsfiddle.net/Azwye/

Comment: Odd! Both your fiddles work exactly as I would like this to, but it doesn't on my machine. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting...

Comment: On jsfiddle, I can replicate your problem using jQuery 1.4.4.  Updating to jQuery to 1.6.2 fixes it, or use Sam Dufel's solution below. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/mqud3/1/). [Further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798949/ie-7-does-not-like-jquerybutton-attrtype-button).

Comment: @Town (and James as well, but SO won't let me tag you): I just noticed (as you can see in my updated post) that this was a jQuery version issue. I can't upgrade at the moment, so I'll resolve to what has been proposed in the answers. Thanks for helping me spotting this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered just doing

```
 $('<button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">Reset all fields</button>').appendTo(target);
```

Comment: +1 Sam, that works consistently across versions (that I've tested, anyway!)

Comment: This works =) For readability purposes, I'll move only the type attribute into the html string, and add the rest with `.attr()`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work is that the `type` attribute of a HTML button is read-only once the button is created.

This means that you can't change the button type afterwards and so, as Sam pointed out in his answer, your best option is to add the type to the button at the same time as you create the button.

```
$('<button type="reset"></button>');
```

If you look in your Error Console while you're developing you'll catch these kinds of errors much quicker.

For the code you've provided, the Firefox Error Console tells us:

```
Error: uncaught exception: type property can't be changed
```

Comment: Chrome's error console didn't give any such error. But setting the type directly in the html string solves the problem. Thanks! =)